# Reading buried JSON items

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to sort goodreads data into a pd data frame but it’s really buried.

The code I’m using is:

```py
with open(r'activity.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file: #opening the JSON file
    data_list_2 = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_list_2)
df.head(5)
```

But the entire file is being put into one column.

When I read the json with a text editor, I have to narrow down json -> index [1] -> activities -> 23,000+ entries to choose from.

My column headers are listed there as activity_type, activity, user, etc

Thank you!’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell without seeing some sample data but off the bat I can say Pandas won't read nested dicts properly. I would recommend you build a parser to extract the data into a flattened dict (with the data you want) and pass that dict to pandas

Comment: Thank you! So parse it to a dictionary then add to data frame.